# Replacing + by 5 in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset called Price which is supposed to be numeric but is generated as a string because all 5 is replaced by +.

It looks like this:

```
"99000"    "98300"    "98300"    "98290"    "98310"    "  9831+ " "98310"    "  9830+ " "  9830+ " "  9830+ " "  9829+ " "  9828+ " "  9827+ " "98270"
```

I used the `gsub` function in R to try and replace + by 5. The code I wrote is:

```
finalPrice<-gsub("+",5,Price)
```

However, the output is just a bunch of numbers which doesn't make sense for what I intended:

```
"59595050505,5 59585350505,5 59585350505,5 59585259505,5 59585351505,5 5 5 595853515+5 5,5 59585351505,5 5 5 595853505+5 5,5 5 5 595853505+5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `finalPrice<-gsub("[+]",5,Price)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The + sign should be escaped. Try this:

```
finalPrice<-gsub("\\+",5, Price)
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides using double-escapes to force a literal-`x` to be matched by the pattern argument, you can also use either the `fixed=TRUE` parameter or use a character-class defined by the "[.]"-operation. See the `?regex` page for more details:

```
> gsub("+", "5", txt, fixed=TRUE)
 [1] "99000"    "98300"    "98300"    "98290"    "98310"   
 [6] "  98315 " "98310"    "  98305 " "  98305 " "  98305 "
[11] "  98295 " "  98285 " "  98275 " "98270"   
> gsub("[+]", "5", txt)
 [1] "99000"    "98300"    "98300"    "98290"    "98310"   
 [6] "  98315 " "98310"    "  98305 " "  98305 " "  98305 "
[11] "  98295 " "  98285 " "  98275 " "98270"
```

Comment: I believe this is also the more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

When writing regex, `+` means *match the preceeding group one or more times*. As the preceeding character is in your regex before the `+` is empty, gsub matches every empty string in the target.

The result is that `5` is inserted into each of these positions.

To avoid this, escape the `+`, which needs to be done with double backslash in R:

`finalPrice<-gsub("\\+",5,Price)`